# KendoUI integration into Durandal JS

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, cordova, durandal

I'm building a phonegap application and plan to use Telerik's Kendo UI framework to generate the UI.  Telerik Kendo UI already has an MVVM implementation and I'd like to use that and not include Knockout JS.  Is this something that is supported, or is Durandal JS deeply integrated with Knockout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Roger Gullhaug has written a blog post, detailing how Durandal can be used together with Kendo UI's data binding: [Using Durandal and KendoUI together](http://rgullhaug.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/using-durandal-and-kendoui-together/)

Also the official Durandal documentation contains a mention about Kendo: [KendoUI](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/KendoUI/)